# vscode one key to override tostring

Tags: visual-studio-code, tostring

I hope one key to override `ToString()` method in **vscode**.

I hope the feature can auto write class variables in `ToString` method.

```
public override void ToString () { return "Name: {0}", this._name; }
```

I found the **vscode** snippet tool, but it can't help my problem.

`ToString()` method is a usually use method, and we will offen change it, when class variable had update.

So i hope **vscode** has this feature.

If you know, please tell me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) sound like the correct approach here. Try creating one like:

```
"toString": {
    "prefix": "toString",
    "body": [
        "public override void ToString () { return \"Name: {0}\", $0; }"
    ]
}
```

Then [setup a keybinding to that snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets):

```
{
  "key": "cmd+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "langId": "csharp",
    "name": "toString"
  }
}
```